# Confluent Kafka Connector Configuration with C# / .net

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I'm trying to build a connector to go into the confluent kafka library.
I have seen many examples in java that use configDef to define the configuration options. However I havent seen anything doing the same in C# and i'm unsure about how to achieve this.

Has anyone made a .net connector for the confluent kafka library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConfigDef is a JVM-only class. Essentially, it's just a Dictionary,  with some extra functionality, though

There is no Kafka Connect compatible API for C#.

If you meant that you want to start a connector from C#, you'd just make a HTTP client with a JSON request; you don't need any ConfigDef